# Selenium, Python: Write, click next page loop

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, test-strategy, debugging

I'm trying to learn `selenium` with `python` and have been trying to automate:

1. `Search` of the `next button` on the page.
2. `Click` on this button.
3. `Save each HTML page` from the next page in a file.
4. Repeat until the `next button` can't be clicked anymore.
5. Quit.

Unfortunately the button persists even when it cannot be clicked. Here is the difference between the two:

When clickable:

```
<input type="image" id="OptionsBar1_imgNext" title="Next" src="/images/toolbaricons/nextsmall.gif" onclick="changeSelect(1);return false;" value="">
```

When not clickable:

```
<input type="image" id="OptionsBar1_imgNext" title="Next" src="/images/toolbaricons/disabled/nextsmall.gif" onclick="changeSelect(1);return false;" value="" disabled="" readonly="">
```

The number of pages is not consistent so I can't define a range of pages. I have had success running through and capturing HTML until the end, but can't get the driver to quit. I imagine this is because I'm not understanding the loop function correctly.

Here is what I have come up with:

```
with open('{}.html'.format(file_name), 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    file.write(driver.page_source)
while True:
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "OptionsBar1_imgNext").get_attribute("src") is "/images/toolbaricons/nextsmall.gif"
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "OptionsBar2_imgNext").click()
    with open('{}.html'.format(file_name), 'a', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
        file.write(driver.page_source)
while False:
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "OptionsBar1_imgNext").get_attribute("src") is "/images/toolbaricons/nextsmall.gif"
    driver.quit()
```

I'm sure this is an elementary question and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to achieve the desired result:

```
while True:
    next_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "OptionsBar1_imgNext")
    src = next_button.get_attribute("src")
    if src == "/images/toolbaricons/nextsmall.gif":
        next_button.click()
        file_name = 'page_{}.html'.format(counter)
        with open(file_name, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
            file.write(driver.page_source)
        counter += 1
    else:
        driver.quit()
        break
```

In this code, we use a while loop to repeat the process until the next button can no longer be clicked. Inside the loop, we find the next button using its ID, get its `src` attribute, and check if it is equal to `"/images/toolbaricons/nextsmall.gif"`. If it is, we click the button and save the current HTML page to a file. If it's not, we quit the driver and break out of the loop. To keep track of the number of pages, we use a counter variable that is incremented each time a new page is saved.